# Pattern Matching with SQL Like for a range of characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to use Pattern Matching with SQL LIKE, to match a variable number of characters with an upper limit?

For example, I have one column which can have "correct values" of 2-10 numbers, anything more than 10 and less than 2 is incorrect.

Comment: Is it a string column or int?

Comment: `case when len(f) between 2 and 10 and isnumeric(f) = 1` ?

Comment: `WHERE col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND BETWEEN 2 AND 10`

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Why don't you post that as an answer. Missed `col` after `And`.  `WHERE col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND col  BETWEEN 2 AND 10`. You like just dba.stackexchange ;)

Comment: @AlexK. `ISNUMERIC()` is a terrible choice. `SELECT ISNUMERIC('1234E2'), ISNUMERIC('$.'), ISNUMERIC('2D5');`

Comment: @Prdp Sorry, typed on a phone. And yeah I stopped answering here long ago.

Comment: @Prdp The 2 and 10 are the number of numeric characters in my varchar column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The 2 and 10 are the number of numeric characters in my varchar column.

Comment: @Christa - Can you post some sample data from your table and expected result

Comment: @Christa yes, I know, it was a typo in two ways. `...AND LEN(col) BETWEEN 2 AND 10`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to use `like` you can do:

```
where col like '__' or col_like '___' or . . .
```

or:

```
where col like '__%'  and        -- at least two characters
      col not like '_________%'  -- not 9 characters
```

The more typical method would be:

```
where len(col) between 2 and 10
```

If you want to ensure they are numbers:

```
where len(col) between 2 and 10 and
      col not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make a function to do this the long way of inspecting each character like below:

```
DECLARE @TempField varchar(max)= '1v3Abc567'

DECLARE @FieldLength int = LEN(@TempField)
DECLARE @CountNumeric int = 0

WHILE @FieldLength > 0
BEGIN
SELECT @CountNumeric = @CountNumeric +  ISNUMERIC( SUBSTRING (@TempField,@FieldLength,1))
SET @FieldLength = @FieldLength - 1
END

SELECT @CountNumeric NumericCount
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Regex.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol LIKE '%[0-9]{2,10}%';
```

should do it (that's off the top of my head, so double-check!

Comment: LIKE has no RegEx support in T-SQL unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like it has something: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(SQL.90).aspx

Although I suspect that `{2,10}` isn't going to work.

Comment: @Grim... Yes I've been referring to that page. And {2,10} doesn't work.